# Publish de aplicativos WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Fiz um publish de um aplicativo WPF com a opção CD-ROM. Bem, percebi que ele cria umas pastas, um Autorun.inf, um setup.exe e um `Nome_Programa.Application`. Fui fazendo uns testes, removendo cada pasta/arquivos gerados, a ponto de remover tudo e deixei apenas o `Nome_Programa.Application` e continuou funcionando. E como fica o app.config? Onde ele seta o acesso ao banco? Ele guarda internamente, mas o arquivo gerado é de apenas 6Kb, não cabe nada dentro.

Comment: Não sei aonde fica o app.config, eu sei que as imagens e os ícones ficam visíveis.

Answer (score 0):

Os programas cuja publicação é gerada pelo no Visual Studio através do ClickOnce, independente do método de instalação selecionado durante o assistente de publicação, serão instalados em uma **subpasta do diretório AppData** e o seu arquivo de configuração estará localizado neste mesmo local, porém esta pasta não pode ser especificada durante a instalação. Uma das possíveis maneiras de descobrir o local de instalação do seu programa:

- Execute o programa de instalação gerado e instale o aplicativo em seu computador.
- O programa será aberto automaticamente após a instalação.
- Abra o gerenciador de tarefas e, na aba **detalhes** (Windows 10) localize o processo correspondente ao seu aplicativo (*ex.: WpfApplication.exe*).
- Clique com o botão secundário do mouse e selecione a entrada de menu **Propriedades**
- A janela de propriedades do processo será aberta, nela é possível ver o **local** onde o aplicativo executável está armazenado. Selecione o diretório e copie ele no explorador de arquivos.
- O seu arquivo de configuração estará armazenado nesta pasta (*ex.: WpfApplication.exe.config*), abra ele com o editor de textos de sua preferência e poderá ver e editar a string de conexão.